# Antlr Tree Pattern Matching with Rewrite Rules

Tags: pattern-matching, antlr, antlr3

I have a trivial antlr grammar for expressions like `a.b.c + d.e.f`:

```
grammar Test;
options {
    output=AST;
}
tokens {
    VARIABLE_ID;
    QUALIFIER_ID;
}

ID  : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*;
DOT : '.';
WS : ( ' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n' ) {$channel=HIDDEN;} ;

variable_id  : id=ID   -> VARIABLE_ID[$id];
qualifier_id  : id=ID   -> QUALIFIER_ID[$id];

expr_start : expr EOF;
expr : var (options {greedy=true;} : '+' expr)*;

var : variable_id (DOT qualifier_id)*;
```

Now I want to define a pattern matcher over this grammar that turns `a.b.c` into `0.1.2`, so I define a Tree Pattern Matcher as follows

```
tree grammar TestWalker;
options {
    tokenVocab=Test;
    ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
    filter=true;
    backtrack=true;
}

@members {
    TokenRewriteStream tokens;

    public void setTreeNodeStream(TreeNodeStream input) {
        super.setTreeNodeStream(input);
        tokens = (TokenRewriteStream)input.getTokenStream(); 
    }
}

topdown : var;

variable_id [int i] : id=VARIABLE_ID {
    tokens.replace($id.getToken(), "" + $i);
};

qualifier_id [int i] : id=QUALIFIER_ID {
    tokens.replace($id.getToken(), "" + $i);
};

var 
@init { int index = 0; }
: variable_id[index] 
(   DOT 
    { ++index; }
    qualifier_id[index]
)*;
```

Then I put together a small test program:

```
import org.antlr.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.runtime.tree.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TestLexer lex = new TestLexer(new ANTLRInputStream(System.in));
        TokenStream tokens = new TokenRewriteStream(lex);

        TestParser parser = new TestParser(tokens);
        TestParser.expr_return expr = parser.expr();

        CommonTreeNodeStream nodes = new CommonTreeNodeStream((Tree)expr.getTree());
        nodes.setTokenStream(tokens);
        TestWalker walker = new TestWalker(nodes);
        walker.downup(expr.getTree());
        System.out.println(tokens.toString());
    }
}
```

When I run this program with basic input, I see surprising results:
`a.b.c` -> `0.b.c`
`a.b + d.e` -> `0.b + 0.e`
and so on.  It appears that the `(DOT qualifier_id)*` portion of my rule never matches and I cannot figure out why.  I have tried adding my rules to the topdown and the bottomup portions of the Tree Pattern Match.  If I switch from a filter matcher to a whole tree matcher and add rules to branch for the `'+'` case appropriately it works, but when the rewrite is just a smaller fragment of a much larger grammar this becomes untenable.  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Update: Using antlr 3.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crux of the issue (as identified by @Bart) is that the parse was not properly generating an AST.  The grammar needs to build the AST (note the addtional `^` tokens).

```
grammar Test;
options {
    output=AST;
}
tokens {
    VARIABLE_ID;
    QUALIFIER_ID;
}

ID  : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*;
DOT : '.';
WS : ( ' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n' ) {$channel=HIDDEN;} ;

variable_id  : id=ID   -> VARIABLE_ID[$id];
qualifier_id  : id=ID   -> QUALIFIER_ID[$id];

expr_start : expr EOF;
expr : var (options {greedy=true;} : '+'^ expr)*;

var : variable_id (DOT^ qualifier_id)*;
```

Then the tree pattern matcher needs to walk the AST as it is constructed.  Note the structure of the expr rule and the arguments used to handle state.

```
tree grammar TestWalker;
options {
    tokenVocab=Test;
    ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
    filter=true;
    backtrack=true;
}

@members {
    TokenRewriteStream tokens;

    public void setTreeNodeStream(TreeNodeStream input) {
        super.setTreeNodeStream(input);
        tokens = (TokenRewriteStream)input.getTokenStream(); 
    }
}

topdown : expr[0];

variable_id returns [int r] : id=VARIABLE_ID {
    $r = 0;
    tokens.replace($id.getToken(), "" + $r);
};

qualifier_id [int i] returns [int r] : id=QUALIFIER_ID {
    $r = $i + 1;
    tokens.replace($id.getToken(), "" + $r);
};

expr [int i] returns [int r]
    : v=variable_id { $r = $v.r; }
    | ^(DOT e=expr[$i] q=qualifier_id[$e.r] { $r = $q.r; } )
    ;
```

Now the output will run as expected:
`a.b + d.e + c.d.e.f`
`0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1.2.3`
and the produced AST looks correct.

[image: output AST]

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with this (relatively new) pattern-tree walking. I glanced over it on the Wiki, but it's not in my copy of the ANTLR reference.

There *is* something not 100% with your Test grammar though: when I generate a parser from it, I get:

```
java -cp antlr-3.2.jar org.antlr.Tool Test.g
warning(200): Test.g:18:46: Decision can match input such as "'+'" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
```

and when I visualize the AST your parser produces using your class (with a small addition):

```
import org.antlr.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.runtime.tree.*;
import org.antlr.stringtemplate.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TestLexer lex = new TestLexer(new ANTLRStringStream("a.b + d.e"));
        TokenStream tokens = new TokenRewriteStream(lex);

        TestParser parser = new TestParser(tokens);
        TestParser.expr_return expr = parser.expr();

        CommonTreeNodeStream nodes = new CommonTreeNodeStream((Tree)expr.getTree());
        nodes.setTokenStream(tokens);

        CommonTree tree = (CommonTree)expr.getTree();

        DOTTreeGenerator gen = new DOTTreeGenerator();
        StringTemplate st = gen.toDOT(tree);
        System.out.println(st);

        TestWalker walker = new TestWalker(nodes);
        walker.downup(tree);
        System.out.println(tokens.toString());
    }
}
```

I see that the input `a.b + d.e` produces the  AST:

[image]

I imagine your tree walker is iterating over said tree, which doesn't surprise me it doesn't produce the desired result since it's just a flat list of nodes with a single root.

Comment: Interesting, that error message does not show up in antlr3.3 (which is what I am using)

Comment: @Matt, well, it's not a serious warning: the lexer & parser _are_ generated after all. What _is_ serious (AFAIK) is the fact that a flat AST is generated. At least, I think your tree-pattern-grammar does not like it... :)

Comment: I see the same thing using DOTTreeGenerator, but when I use antlr works I see a full parse tree.

Comment: @Matt, ANTLRWorks creates a parse tree on its own (which is not available to you). To create a proper AST, see this [previous Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931346/how-to-output-the-ast-built-using-antlr).

Comment: @Bart Thanks, let me chug on this for a while and get back to you.

Comment: @Matt, no problem. Post back if you have other problems!