# How should I construct and walk the AST output of an ANTLR3 grammar?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, antlr, abstract-syntax-tree

Documentation and general advice is that the abstract syntax tree should omit tokens that have no meaning. ("Record the meaningful input tokens (and only the meaningful tokens" - The Definitive ANTLR Reference) IE: In a C++ AST, you would omit the braces at the start and end of the class, as they have no meaning and are simply a mechanism for delineating class start and end for parsing purposes. I understand that, for the sake of rapidly and efficiently walking the tree, culling out useless token nodes like that is useful, but in order to appropriately colorize code, I would need that information, even if it doesn't contribute to the meaning of the code. **A) Is there any reason why I shouldn't have the AST serve multiple purposes and choose not to omit said tokens?**

It seems to me that what ANTLRWorks interpreter outputs is what I'm looking for. In the ANTLRWorks interpreter, it outputs a tree diagram where, for each rule matched, a node is made, as well as a child node for each token and/or subrule. The parse tree, I suppose it's called.

If manually walking a tree, wouldn't it be more useful to have nodes marking a rule? By having a node marking a rule, with it's subrules and tokens as children, a manual walker doesn't need to look ahead several nodes to know the context of what node it's on. Tree grammars seem redundant to me. Given a tree of AST nodes, the tree grammar "parses" the nodes all over again in order to produce some other output. **B) Given that the parser grammar was responsible for generating correctly formed ASTs and given the inclusion of rule AST nodes, shouldn't a manual walker avoid the redundant AST node pattern matching of a tree grammar?**

I fear I'm wildly misunderstanding the tree grammar mechanism's purpose. A tree grammar more or less defines a set of methods that will run through a tree, look for a pattern of nodes that matches the tree grammar rule, and execute some action based on that. I can't depend on forming my AST output based on what's neat and tidy for the tree grammar (omitting meaningless tokens for pattern matching speed) yet use the AST for color-coding even the meaningless tokens. I'm writing an IDE as well;  I also can't write every possible AST node pattern that a plugin author might want to match, nor do I want to require them using ANTLR to write a tree grammar. In the case of plugin authors walking the tree for their own criteria, rule nodes would be rather useful to avoid needing pattern matching.

Thoughts? I know this "question" might push the limits of being an SO question, but I'm not sure how else to formulate my inquiries or where else to inquire.

Comment: Good question. Note that I took the liberty to change the tag `antlr3` to `antlr` since your question is not just applicable to the 3rd version of ANTLR. I would have just added the tag, but there can only be a total of 5 tags added to a question.

Comment: @Sion:  You had asked a question earlier about having a `class B { std::vector<B> x; };` or some similar situation involving a `std::vector` of an incomplete type.  You've deleted that question, saying that it works.  It doesn't really work:  you cannot instantiate a Standard Library container with an incomplete type.  It may compile but the results are undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Sion Sheevok wrote:*
>
> **A) Is there any reason why I shouldn't have the AST serve multiple purposes and choose not to omit said tokens?**

No, you mind as well keep them in there.

> *Sion Sheevok wrote:*
>
> It seems to me that what ANTLRWorks interpreter outputs is what I'm looking for. In the ANTLRWorks interpreter, it outputs a tree diagram where, for each rule matched, a node is made, as well as a child node for each token and/or subrule. The parse tree, I suppose it's called.

Correct.

> *Sion Sheevok wrote:*
>
> **B) Given that the parser grammar was responsible for generating correctly formed ASTs and given the inclusion of rule AST nodes, shouldn't a manual walker avoid the redundant AST node pattern matching of a tree grammar?**

Tree grammars are often used to mix custom code in to evaluate/interpret the input source. If you mix this code inside the parser grammar *and* there's some backtracking going on in the parser, this custom code could be executed more than it's supposed to. Walking the tree using a tree grammar is (if done properly) only possible in one way causing custom code to be executed just once.

But *if* a separate tree walker/iterator is necessary, there are two camps out there that advocate using tree grammars and others opt for walking the tree manually with a custom iterator. Both camps raise valid points about their preferred way of walking the AST. So there's no clear-cut way to do it in one specific way.

> *Sion Sheevok wrote:*
>
> Thoughts?

Since you're not evaluating/interpreting, you mind as well not use a tree grammar.

But to create a parse tree as ANTLRWorks does (which you have no access to, btw), you will need to mix AST rewrite rules inside your parser grammar though. Here's a Q&A that explains how to do that: [How to output the AST built using ANTLR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931346/how-to-output-the-ast-built-using-antlr)

Good luck!

Comment: I intend to evaluate/interpret the tree as well to generate the intermediate code representation, but I can do that even with meaningless tokens. Thank you very much! Up-voted and marked as answer.