# antlr rewriting output of a rule

Tags: url-rewriting, antlr, stringtemplate

I am trying to write an antlr script where in, rule1 has a subrule , rule2. I am using StringTemplate on rule 1.

What I want to do, is restructure the text matched by rule2 before it is consumed/used by rule1. How do I do that ?

```
options{
output=template;
}

rule1 :
  begin sub-rule2 end ';' -> meth(body={rule1.text})

sub-rule2 :
   sub-rule3
 | sub-rule4
 | sub-rule5;
```

here "meth" is the stringtemplate call

If say sub-rule 4 matches "select * from dual;", I would like this to be passed to rule1  "#sql (select * from dual);".

> Here is my Actual code I would like the statements matched by the select_statement rule to be wrapped in '#sql()' and to be passed in "stats" list to the "body" attribute of the "meth" template :

```
body 
@init {
      List stats = new ArrayList();
    }   :   
    BEGIN s=statement{ stats.add($s.text); } SEMI ( s=statement{ stats.add($s.text); } SEMI | pragma SEMI )*
    ( EXCEPTION exception_handler+ )? END ID? -> method(modifiers={"public"},returnType={"void"},name={"execute"},body={stats})
    ;


statement :
    label*
    ( assign_or_call_statement
    | case_statement
    | close_statement
    | continue_statement
    | basic_loop_statement
    | execute_immediate_statement
    | exit_statement
    | fetch_statement
    | for_loop_statement
    | forall_statement
    | goto_statement
    | if_statement
    | null_statement
    | open_statement
    | plsql_block
    | raise_statement
    | return_statement
    | sql_statement 
    | while_loop_statement
    ) 
    ;

    sql_statement
    : (commit_statement
    | delete_statement
    | insert_statement
    | lock_table_statement
    | rollback_statement
    | savepoint_statement
    | select_statement 
    | set_transaction_statement
    | update_statement )
    ;


    select_statement :
        SELECT swallow_to_semi 
    ;

    SELECT  :   'select';

    swallow_to_semi :
        ~( SEMI )+
    ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specifically define what a rule can return like this:

```
sub_rule2 returns [String x] 
  :  sub_rule3 {$x = ... }
  |  sub_rule4 {$x = "#sql (" + $sub_rule4.text + ");";}
  |  sub_rule5 {$x = ... }
  ;
```

Now `sub_rule2` returns a `String x` which you can use like this:

```
rule1
  :  ... sub_rule2 ... -> meth(body={sub_rule2.x})
  ;
```

Note the `sub_rule2.x`.

### EDIT

You could also create a custom method that checks if the text to be added to the `List` starts with `"select "` like this:

```
grammar YourGrammarName;

options{
  output=template;
}

@parser::members {
  private void addStat(String stat, List<String statList>) {
    // 1. if `stat` starts with "select ", wrap "#sql(...)" around it.
    // 2. add `stat` to `statList`
  }
}

body 
@init {
  List<String> stats = new ArrayList<String>();
}   
  :  BEGIN s=statement { addStat($s.text, stats); } SEMI 
     ( s=statement     { addStat($s.text, stats); } SEMI 
     | pragma                                      SEMI
     )*
     (EXCEPTION exception_handler+)? END ID? 

     -> method(modifiers={"public"},returnType={"void"},name={"execute"},body={stats})
  ;
```

Comment: Thanks Bart. The problem with this one is that I will have to define return type and {$x = ... } for all the sub rules between rule 1 and rule 2.  The example I gave above was stripped down version of actual scenario. Actually, there are 4/5 subrules/levels between the first one and the last one .. is there any other way to achieve this , in such a situation ?

Comment: I've updated the original problem description with actual case, thanks.

Comment: Thanks Bart. That's one way of doing it, which I tried and works. I would still want to be able to do this within the sql_statement rule, which I think would be a lot cleaner. Since, if you look at the 'statement' rule, it can match lot of subrules, like sql_statement, sql_block, etc, in which case, I'll have to have a huge method in the @members, handling cases for each one of them .. and this is just 'statement' rule. There are all other rules within the grammer, who will match some text or other, which will again need to be passed through 'body'. This will become unmaintainable for sure.

Comment: An update, I tried something and it worked !
Modified 'statement' rule like this  :
`code`
statement returns [String xx]:
    label*
    ( assign_or_call_statement
    ..
    | sql_statement {$xx = $sql_statement.x;}
    | while_loop_statement
    ) {if ($xx==null) $xx = $statement.text;}
    ;
`code`
and in the 'body' rule, 

BEGIN s=statement{ stats.add($s.xx); } ..

Comment: this way, I do not have to define { $xx = ... ;} for every subrule.

Comment: Now the question is how do I replace this with StringTemplate. I would like to define a template for sql_statement in the string template ( .stg ) like this : 
sql(st) ::= <<
#sql (<st>);
>>  and use it in the grammer.

Comment: again, with some research, i was able to accomplish this like this :
    | sql_statement-> sql(stt={$sql_statement.text}) in 'statement' rule and then using "st" attribute of the rule .... stats.add($s.st) in 'body' rule.  

Listing here, so may help others reading this thread ..