# Antlr Tree traversing using Java

Tags: java, antlr, antlr3

I have a question regarding Antlr, I am building a simple parser with it but I can't traverse the tree. I have found many online tutorials and they use a `getAst();` function of the Parser class. Does anyone have any experience with this? I have the feeling that the way of doing this differs per version.

```
grammar SimpleCalc;

options 
{
    output=AST; 
} 

tokens {
    PLUS    = '+' ;
    MINUS   = '-' ;
    MULT    = '*' ;
    DIV = '/' ;
    SEMICOLON = ';';
    EQUAL = '=';
    COMMA = ',';
    BRACKETL = '(';
    BRACKETR = ')';
}
```

Anyone have any idea, or suggestions on how to traverse the tree in an alternative way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getAST()` is a method from `CommonAST` which is used in ANTLR v2.x.

ANTLR v3.x uses `CommonTree` instead. When defining `output=AST`, all parser rules return an instance of [`RuleReturnScope`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/classorg_1_1antlr_1_1runtime_1_1_rule_return_scope.html) which has a `getTree()` method you can use the get the tree.

Also see this previous Q&A that shows how the get hold of the AST after parsing some input: [How to output the AST built using ANTLR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931346/how-to-output-the-ast-built-using-antlr)

Comment: Great! Thank you, quite easy accutally when you know how Antlr is structured.