# AST rule for relop operations in ANTLR

Tags: compiler-construction, antlr

I wonder to know how can I write a rewrite rule to generate AST tree for this rule.

```
e5    : (simpleexpression) (relop simpleexpression)* 
      ;

relop : RELOP_GT 
      | RELOP_LT 
      | RELOP_GE 
      | RELOP_LE 
      ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a binary operation where the root of the (sub) tree is the operator, `relop`, and the leaves are the `simpleexpression`s. In that case, simply use the inline tree-operator `^`, which makes the token/tree before it the root:

```
e5    : simpleexpression (relop^ simpleexpression)? 
      ;

relop : RELOP_GT 
      | RELOP_LT 
      | RELOP_GE 
      | RELOP_LE 
      ;
```

Note that I changes the `*` into `?` since your original rule would accept input like:

```
1 <= 2 < 3
```

In many programming languages that would evaluate to:

```
true < 3
```

which might be considered an invalid expression (your language might accept it, of course, in which case, leave the `*`!).

With the inline `^`, the expression

```
1 <= 2
```

would be parsed into the following AST:

```
  <=
 /  \
1    2
```

Also see: [How to output the AST built using ANTLR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931346/how-to-output-the-ast-built-using-antlr/4933963)