# Antlr3 .Net how to build a simple grammar

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I'm trying to build a simple grammar to parse a .Net type name string, supporting generics. I admit to being completely new to building grammars in any language. A type string might look like the following.

```
Foo.Bar.Blah(Mom.Dad, Son.Daughter(Frank.Bob), Dog)
```

Basically, it's recursive. Ya'll should understand this.

I'm completely out in the woods with this one. Not sure how to begin. What I've built currently, which doesn't actually work, is this:

```
tree grammar XmlTypeName;

options {
    language=CSharp2;
}

RPAREN
  : '('
  ;

LPAREN
  : ')'
  ;

SEP
  : ','
  ;

TYPE  
  : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')+
  ;

prog
  : type;

type
  : TYPE (RPAREN type (SEP type)? LPAREN)? (EOF)?
  ;
```

This doesn't even get close to working. Antlr3.exe throws errors saying that RPARAM and LPARAM aren't allowed in a tree parser. Is a tree parser even what I need?

I'd like to produce a simple AST that lets me navigate down the types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you shouldn't use a tree grammar. A tree grammar is used *after* a parser has created an AST. Simply remove the keyword `tree` from it.

A couple of other remarks:

- you want to match one or more comma separated `type`s inside parenthesis, but you used `type (SEP type)?`, which matches one or two `type`s. You'll need `type (SEP type)*` instead;
- you didn't account for the `.` inside the `type`s;
- you should discard literal spaces in the lexer.

Something like this will do the trick, most probably:

```
grammar XmlTypeName;

options {
  language=CSharp2;
}

prog
 : type EOF
 ;

type
 : name (RPAREN type (SEP type)* LPAREN)? 
 ;

name
 : ID (DOT ID)*
 ;

RPAREN
 : '('
 ;

LPAREN
 : ')'
 ;

SEP
 : ','
 ;

DOT
 : '.'
 ;

ID  
 : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')+
 ;

SPACE
 : (' '|'\t')+ {Skip();} // if 'Skip()' doesn't work, try 'skip()'
 ;
```

However, the above just creates a flat list of tokens. If you want to create a proper AST, you need to "tell" ANTLR which nodes/tokens are root tokens, and which ones to discard (like the comma's, parenthesis, ...).

```
grammar XmlTypeName;

options {
  output=AST;
  language=CSharp2;
}

tokens {
  TYPE;
  NAME;
}

prog
 : type EOF -> type
 ;

type
 : name (RPAREN type (SEP type)* LPAREN)? -> ^(TYPE name type*)
 ;

name
 : ID (DOT ID)* -> ^(NAME ID+)
 ;

RPAREN
 : '('
 ;

LPAREN
 : ')'
 ;

SEP
 : ','
 ;

DOT
 : '.'
 ;

ID  
 : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')+
 ;

SPACE
 : (' '|'\t')+ {skip();}
 ;
```

which creates the following AST:

[image]

More info about creating AST's with ANTLR: [How to output the AST built using ANTLR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931346/how-to-output-the-ast-built-using-antlr)

Comment: Thanks! After about 2 hours on this, I managed to figure out that I needed to split out ID, and the 'name' parsing much in the same way as the type list ',' parsing. But that just produced a flat tree. I'm still a little unsure what the syntax here actually means. -> is a rewrite, so it alters the tokens out of the lexer... got that... but what's the meaning of ^()?

Comment: No problem. The AST operators are explained in the link I posted at the end of my answer.

Comment: Also, It's actually emitting NAME '(' TYPE ',' TYPE ',' TYPE ')' in the AST. How do I have it hide the ('s from the AST? Or should I even bother?

Comment: The way I showed it, the `'('`, `')'` and `','` *are* omitted from the AST: try it. Also read the link I posted at the end: it will explain how to omit or include tokens in the AST.

Comment: @wasabi, if you're using my second example and you're seeing the parenthesis and comma's, you're probably using ANTLRWorks' interpreter: don't, it a bit buggy. Use ANTLRWorks' debugger instead (which shows the actual AST that is created, not only the parse tree).