# How can I build an ANTLR Works style parse tree?

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I've read that you need to use the '^' and '!' operators in order to build a parse tree similar to the ones displayed in ANTLR Works (even though you don't need to use them to get a nice tree in ANTLR Works).  My question then is how can I build such a tree?  I've seen a few pages on tree construction using the two operators and rewrites, and yet say I have an input string `abc abc123` and a grammar:

```
grammar test;

program : idList;
idList : id* ;
id : ID ;

ID : LETTER (LETTER | NUMBER)* ;
LETTER : 'a' .. 'z' | 'A' .. 'Z' ;
NUMBER : '0' .. '9' ;
```

ANTLR Works will output:

[image: ANTLR Works Interpreter Output]

What I dont understand is how you can get the 'idList' node on top of this tree (as well as the grammar one as a matter of fact).  How can I reproduce this tree using rewrites and those operators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I dont understand is how you can get the 'idList' node on top of this tree (as well as the grammar one as a matter of fact). How can I reproduce this tree using rewrites and those operators?

You can't use `^` and `!` alone. These operators only operate on existing tokens, while you want to create extra tokens (and make these the root of your sub trees). You *can* do that using [rewrite rules and defining some *imaginary* tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931346/how-to-output-the-ast-built-using-antlr).

A quick demo:

```
grammar test;

options {
  output=AST;
  ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
}

tokens {
  IdList;
  Id;
}

@parser::members {

  private static void walk(CommonTree tree, int indent) {
    if(tree == null) return;
    for(int i = 0; i < indent; i++, System.out.print("    "));
    System.out.println(tree.getText());
    for(int i = 0; i < tree.getChildCount(); i++) {
      walk((CommonTree)tree.getChild(i), indent + 1);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    testLexer lexer = new testLexer(new ANTLRStringStream("abc abc123"));
    testParser parser = new testParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    walk((CommonTree)parser.program().getTree(), 0);
  }
}

program : idList EOF -> idList;
idList  : id*        -> ^(IdList id*);
id      : ID         -> ^(Id ID);

ID    : LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT)*;
SPACE : ' ' {skip();};

fragment LETTER : 'a' .. 'z' | 'A' .. 'Z';
fragment DIGIT  : '0' .. '9';
```

If you run the demo above, you will see the following being printed to the console:

```
IdList
    Id
        abc
    Id
        abc123
```

As you can see, imaginary tokens must also start with an upper case letter, just like lexer rules. If you want to give the imaginary tokens the same `text` as the parser rule they represent, do something like this instead:

```
idList  : id*        -> ^(IdList["idList"] id*);
id      : ID         -> ^(Id["id"] ID);
```

which will print:

```
idList
    id
        abc
    id
        abc123
```

Comment: Thanks for such an in depth answer.  For whatever reason I was never able to get that from the documentation.