# ANTLR - Remove node from AST

Tags: antlr, nodes, abstract-syntax-tree

I am creating my first AST. I want to remove the '=' from it.

I'm having something like:

```
              BLOCK
                |
          |-----------|
     STATEMENTS     RETURN
          |
     ASSIGNMENT
          |
          |
    |-----|-----|
 field    =    value


An extract from my Grammar file:

parse
  :  block EOF -> block
  ;

block
  :  (statement)* (Return Identifier ';')? 
     -> ^(BLOCK ^(STATEMENTS statement*) ^(RETURN Identifier?))
  ;

statement
  :  assignment ';'   -> assignment
  ;

assignment
   :  expression 
   -> ^(ASSIGNMENT expression)
   ;

expression
    :   NAME '=' Identifier
    ;
```

So, how can I remove the '=' node that is print in the tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By either using the inline operator `!` that discards nodes from the tree:

```
expression
    :   NAME '='! Identifier
    ;
```

or by using a rewrite operator:

```
expression
    :   NAME '=' Identifier -> NAME Identifier
    ;
```

Related Q&A that explains these operators: [How to output the AST built using ANTLR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931346/how-to-output-the-ast-built-using-antlr)

Note that there is no `ASSIGNMENT` token in your grammar. If you want to inject such a token, put it in your `tokens{ ... }` block and insert it in a rewrite rule:

```
grammar T;

options {
  // ...
}

tokens {
  ASSIGNMENT;
}

statement
    :  assignment ';' -> assignment
    ;

expression
    :   NAME '=' Identifier -> ^(ASSIGNMENT NAME Identifier)
    ;
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. The ASSIGNMENT token existed. I didn't post my whole grammar file.