# Antlr - Expression parser and evaluator

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I am required to write a boolean expression parser/evaluator.
The expressions would be of the form and would be enclosed in parenthesis :

```
exp1 : (A = B)
exp2 : ((A = B) AND (C = D))
exp3 : ((A = B) AND ((C = D) OR (E = F)))
exp4: (((A = B) AND (C = D)) OR (E = F))
```

and it goes on. The rule may contain 'n' number of expressions with proper grouping 2 in each group. My grammar file looks like this:

```
/*
Expression grammar
 */

grammar Exparser;

options

{
    language = Java;
}
cond    :   
tc EOF;

tc:
      exp
  | binary_exp
| leftparen* exp ( binaryop leftparen* exp rightparen+)*
| leftparen* exp ( binaryop leftparen* exp rightparen*)*

;

binary_exp:
 '(' exp BINARYOP exp ')'
;

binaryop:
            BINARYOP
        ;
leftparen:
             LEFTPARN
         ;

rightparen:
              RIGHTPARN
          ;

exp:
LEFTPARN VARIABLE COMPOP VARIABLE RIGHTPARN

;

variable:
            VARIABLE;


BINARYOP: AND | OR;
COMPOP: EQUAL | LT | GT | LTE | GTE | NE;
VARIABLE: (CHAR)+;
LEFTPARN: '(';
RIGHTPARN: ')';
EQUAL: '=' | 'EQ';
LT: '<' | 'LT';

GT:'>' | 'GT';
LTE: '<=';
GTE: '>=';
NE  :   '!=' | 'NE';
AND: 'AND' | '&' | 'and';

OR: 'OR' | 'or';

CHAR  :   'a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_' |'0'..'9'|'-' | '.'
   ;
```

this grammar works fine, but I am not able to achieve the depth in the AST. for example exp3 is parsed as three `exp` and not as one `exp` and one `binary_exp`.
Also how do I evaluate a boolean expression using my parser? 
How does my grammar enforce balancing of parenthesis?
Though [Nested Boolean Expression Parser using ANTLR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30976962/nested-boolean-expression-parser-using-antlr) give some idea for evaluating an expression, I am not able to apply in my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parser generated from the following grammar parses all your example input:

```
grammar Exparser;

parse
 : expr EOF
 ;

expr
 : expr binop expr
 | VARIABLE
 | '(' expr ')'
 ;

binop
 : AND | OR | EQUAL | LT | GT | LTE | GTE | NE
 ;

EQUAL     : '=' | 'EQ';
LT        : '<' | 'LT';
GT        : '>' | 'GT';
LTE       : '<=';
GTE       : '>=';
NE        : '!=' | 'NE';
AND       : 'AND' | '&' | 'and';
OR        : 'OR' | 'or';
VARIABLE  : [a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+;
SPACE     : [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

Evaluating these expressions should be the same as [the Q&A you linked to in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30976962/nested-boolean-expression-parser-using-antlr).

Comment: Thanks Bart . I could get my tree structure when I ran this on antlrworks 2. I am yet to work on the evaluation part.

Comment: The grammar worked like a charm. I made simple modifications to suit my needs. For me the expressions in my applications are fairly static once defined. I was thinking to write the parse tree to disk but found that it's not possible since the classes are not Serializable. Is there any other proven method to do this ?

Comment: I've not yet looked into serializing/persisting ANTLR 4 classes.

Comment: Thank you so much Bart. For a beginner in ANTLR like me, your answer helped a lot. I found an another way to store the parse tree. Convert the AST to an xml using the ANTLR generated listener and store it to disk. When I evaluate the rule next time, I read the xml file and walk thru the nodes using a xml tree walker to evaluate the expression

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: I don't know antlr.  However, I think you need to make your grammar more explicit.  You are overloading `exp` too much.  Try something like this pseudocode:

```
tc <- binary_exp ;
binary_exp <- comparison_exp
            | LEFTPARN binary_exp RIGHTPARN
            | LEFTPARN binary_exp BINARYOP binary_exp RIGHTPARN ;
comparison_exp <- LEFTPARN VARIABLE COMPOP VARIABLE RIGHTPARN ;
```

- Every `tc` is a binary expression `binary_exp`.
- A binary expression is one of:

  - a comparison expression `comparison_exp`,
  - a binary expression surrounded by parentheses (`LEFTPARN` and `RIGHTPARN`),
  - or a sequence of left-parenthesis `LEFTPARN`, a `binary_exp`, a binary operator `BINARYOP`, a `binary_exp`, and a right-parenthesis `RIGHTPARN`.
- a comparison expression is a sequence of left-parenthesis `LEFTPARN`, a variable `VARIABLE`, a comparison operator `COMPOP`, a `VARIABLE`, and a right-parenthesis `RIGHTPARN`.

This grammar would allow binary expressions to be nested inside extra parentheses or nested inside one another, but comparison expressions cannot have other expressions nested inside them.